# LIFO Handler in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, asynchronous

I have a bunch of asynchronous tasks I need to be run, but the task with the highest priority is the one that was added last.

**Is there a LIFO (last in first out) stack-like `Handler` in Android** that I can use for this?

If not, my alternative implementation is to have each task pull an item to process from a `Stack`. But this is causing issues with locking as the stack is populated dynamically. Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Thread.  In the thread, create a LinkedBlockingDeque.  When adding a task, add it to the head of the dequeue.  In the thread, poll() on it (which will remove the head when one exists).  The class itself will handle all locking.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily implement from scratch a thread which feeds from a LinkedBlockingDeque. Users can put tasks to both sides of the deque.